# Does golang has capbility to handle process and thread besides routine

Tags: multithreading, go, concurrency

I know that golang is using go routine implementing the concurrency.  I assume go routine is lighter on weight than thread, one thread could have many routines.  How does the golang manage threads and routines?  Is golang always running a single thread like Node.js?  Or Golang manages a lot of threads and creates more routines on these threads?  Does golang providing some lib to touch the Process/Thread on OS level?

Comment: Are you asking how *you* can control the number of OS threads used? Read about GOMAXPROCS in the [runtime package documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/)

Answer (score 0):

Go does manage a lot of threads and creates more routines on these threads. Go doesn't provide access to Process/Thread/Goroutine, them even haven't a names. Only channels in Go have names.